# (resolved) Magento 2 : Setup\InstallSchema.php seems ignored, why and how to debug

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 (0.74.0-beta10) seems to ignore the Setup\InstallSchema.php of my module. The module is correctly enabled - and i can see him on frontend with the route. I don't find what script load the InstallSchemas, to debug it. Anyone knows what's going on ?

Here's my InstallSchema.php :

```
<?php

namespace Tb\Staff\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface, UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        /**
         * Create table
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('staffmember')
        )->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Id'
        /*)->addColumn( 'Staff_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'default' => '1'],
            'Staff Id'
        )->addColumn( 'customer_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => true ],
            'Magento Customer Id of this Staff Staff'*/
        )->addColumn(
            'firstname',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            55,
            [],
            'First '
        )->addColumn(
            'lastname',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            55,
            [],
            'Last name'
        )->addColumn(
            'job',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            55,
            [],
            'Job intitle'
        )->addColumn(
            'bio',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_BLOB,
            null,
            [],
            'Biography'
        )->addColumn(
            'picture',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Picture URL'
        )->addColumn(
            'email',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            128,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'User Email'
        )->addColumn(
            'twitter',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'User Twitter @username'
        )->addColumn(
            'linkedin',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'User LinkedIn URL'
        )->addColumn(
            'username',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            40,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'User Code'
        )->addColumn(
            'is_active',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => 1],
            'Is Active flag'
        )->setComment(
            'Eca Staff Members'
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $installer->endSetup();

    }
}
```

The module is found by setup:upgrade, but do nothing with it.

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
C:/xampp/htdocs/www/tb/mage2/var/
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Tb_Staff':
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Backup':
.....
```

Comment: What a load of crap to close this question. I had a very similar problem, reproducible and not due to a typo or such. Setup:upgrade never installed the schema for me neither, but when I added UpgradeSchema class it created the table for me.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd recommend you to make mistake in your class to understand if it calls. If it calls - during `setup:upgrade` you will see error message.

If you have already installed module and in `setup` database table there is such value - most probably InstallSchema will never execute. If so - use UpgradeSchema (look at another magento modules.)

Comment: Thanks zhartaunik. Yes, I tried both cases. A also created (after) and UpgradeSchema, modifying the version number of the module each time. Maybe there is some config in etc to declare that Magento must look the Setup directory ?

Comment: What has happened when you did a mistake in code?

Comment: I write a new answer below, because my texte was too big to add it in comment.

Comment: I created an other module more basic to test, and the fact that I created a new module, makes Magento 2 correctly upgrading my previous one... Sad cache bug, I guess. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fact it detects an error only show that's it will include the class, but not necesarily executing the upgrade() function, right ?

PS : if I execute schema:upgrade without incrementing the module version, it doesn't display me the error, meaning it include the setup class only when it tries to execute it ? So why nothing happens...

The class I added an error :

```
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

ssssssssss
        /**
         * Create table
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('staffmember')
        )->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Id'
        /*)->addColumn( 'Staff_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'default' => '1'],
            'Staff Id'
        )->addColumn( 'customer_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => true ],
            'Magento Customer Id of this Staff Staff'*/
        )->addColumn(
            'firstname',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            55,
            [],
            'First '
        )->addColumn(
            'lastname',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            55,
            [],
            'Last name'
        )->addColumn(
            'job',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            55,
            [],
            'Job intitle'
        )->addColumn(
            'bio',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_BLOB,
            null,
            [],
            'Biography'
        )->addColumn(
            'picture',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Picture URL'
        )->addColumn(
            'email',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            128,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'User Email'
        )->addColumn(
            'twitter',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'User Twitter @username'
        )->addColumn(
            'linkedin',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'User LinkedIn URL'
        )->addColumn(
            'username',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            40,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'User Code'
        )->addColumn(
            'is_active',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => 1],
            'Is Active flag'
        )->setComment(
            'Staff Members'
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $installer->endSetup();

    }
}
```

The error message :

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
C:/xampp/htdocs/www/client/mage2/var/generation/Magento
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Tb_Staff':

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$table' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\app\code\Eca\Staff\Setup\UpgradeSchema.php on line 29

Call Stack:
    0.0005     122424   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\bin\magento:0
   28.4184   35557248   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\bin\magento:12
   28.4351   35812832   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:126
   28.4359   35813272   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.
   28.4359   35813480   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:8
   28.4364   35815072   6. Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand->execute() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Co
   28.6466   36192392   7. Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand.php:56
   28.7762   37366304   8. Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:694
   28.9307   37755120   9. Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->getSchemaDataHandler() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:745
   28.9307   37755328  10. Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->createSchemaDataHandler() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:1148
   28.9307   37755360  11. class_exists() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:825
   28.9307   37755560  12. spl_autoload_call() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:825
   28.9307   37755600  13. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:0
   28.9311   37755808  14. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() C:\xampp\htdocs\www\client\mage2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:301
```

Comment: same issue here